# Application is getting crash on presenting on UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

When user is clicking on message option , my app is getting crash.
I am using below code to show the activityView.

```
 @IBAction func shareButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let shareText = "Hello, world!"
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText], applicationActivities: [])
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

```
2018-08-20 22:36:31.719463+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter => com.apple.share.Twitter.post
2018-08-20 22:36:31.719645+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFacebook => com.apple.share.Facebook.post
2018-08-20 22:36:31.719749+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToWeibo => com.apple.share.SinaWeibo.post
2018-08-20 22:36:31.719862+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.TencentWeibo => com.apple.share.TencentWeibo.post
2018-08-20 22:36:31.719954+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFlickr => com.apple.share.Flickr.post
2018-08-20 22:36:31.720041+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [core] SLComposeViewController extensionIdentifierForActivityType: com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToVimeo => com.apple.share.Vimeo.post
2018-08-20 22:36:31.765646+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: com.verizontelematics.Verizon-Hum, source account management: 1
2018-08-20 22:36:31.768863+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [MC] Result: YES
2018-08-20 22:36:31.769095+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: com.verizontelematics.Verizon-Hum, source account management: 1
2018-08-20 22:36:31.771958+0530 PreProd[512:126327] [MC] Result: YES
2018-08-20 22:36:37.098335+0530 PreProd[512:126327] -[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170c4bb20
2018-08-20 22:36:37.099382+0530 PreProd[512:126327] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170c4bb20'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Show the code for message option. You have probably not set the target properly for selector.

Comment: More code is needed, this does not look like the source of the error

Comment: That is the full code.

Comment: @aashishnagar Show all the code you have.

Comment: When invoking an action from a UI response you don't need to add the `DispatchQueue.main.async` operation. Can you remove the dispatch async block and retry the presentation without that block?

Comment: This is the only relevant code

Comment: no removing it does not make any diff,

Comment: The error message says that the error is related to `NSCoding`, probably this code doesn't cause the crash